# Is it necessary to extend every model class with RealmObject while working with realm?

Tags: android, realm

I am using Realm ORM for my app. I have 3 model classes of which two extends *RealmObject* while the other one does not.

```
public class Party extends RealmObject implements Parcelable {
    @PrimaryKey
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String name_en;
    public String name_ne;
    public String address;
    public String phoneNumber;
    public String taxRegistrationNumber;
    public String partyType;
```

the second class holds a field of type Party. But this does not extends RealmObject

```
public class CreatePurchaseOrder implements Parcelable {
    public int voucherNumber;
    public Date date;
    public Party party;
    String agent;
```

The third class holds a field for CreatePurchaseOrder and extends RealmObject

```
[public class CreatePurchaseOrderRow extends RealmObject implements Parcelable {
    @PrimaryKey
    public int id;
    private int serialNumber;
    private String specification;
    private float quantity;
    private float rate;
    private String remarks;
    private boolean fulfilled;
    private CreatePurchaseOrder createPurchaseOrder;
```

With this approach it generates an error message 
[screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKl81.png)

[image: screenshot of error message]

So is it necessary to extend every Model class with RealmObject?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Technically you don't have to extend `RealmObject` directly from your model class.

The [docs](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#models) say:

> Realm model classes are created by extending the RealmObject base class.

Which implies that if you don't extend `RealmObject`, your class is not a `Realm` model, thus it can't be stored in a realm.

However you can also implement the `RealmModel` interface and annotate your model class with `@RealmClass`

```
@RealmClass
public class MyModel implements RealmModel {

}
```

as mentioned [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#why-do-model-classes-need-to-extend-realmobject):

> **Why do model classes need to extend RealmObject?**
>
> We need to add Realm specific functionality to your model classes. It also allows us to use generics in our APIs, making it easier to read and use. *If you don’t want to extend a base class you can instead implement the RealmModel interface.*

and [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#realmmodel-interface):

> An alternative to extending the RealmObject base class is implementing the RealmModel interface and adding the @RealmClass annotation.

It is a different means to achieve the same goal. The issue you experience is the same though. You cannot store plain objects in a realm. You **must** hook up your model class to Realm using one of two ways mentioned above.

Do note that if you use the 2nd approach, the usage is different:

```
// With RealmObject
myModel.isValid();

// With RealmModel
RealmObject.isValid(myModel);
```

Comment: BTW, it is also fine to implements `RealmModel` and annotate the class with `@RealmClass`

Comment: @beeender interesting, thanks for mentioning. Is this documented?

Comment: Actually we didn't forget to document it :) https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#realmmodel-interface It was added some months ago.

Comment: @beeender neat :-) had not seen that part before. I'll add it

Comment: @beeender this part of the docs (https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#why-do-model-classes-need-to-extend-realmobject) doesn't mention that you have to annotate class with `@RealmClass`. May be nice to add it :-)

Comment: I think it was added in 0.89.1

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yeah, like EPF said, it has been added? "We need to add Realm specific functionality to your model classes. It also allows us to use generics in our APIs, making it easier to read and use. If you don’t want to extend a base class you can instead implement the RealmModel interface." So you think it is a bit misleading?